# Como capturo la informacion de un archivo en input file JS?

Tags: javascript, html, json, input-file

tengo la siguiente duda: Agregué en mi proyecto un input de tipo File, en donde necesito subir un json y despues trabajar con el contenido de ese json.

Hice una función sencilla para saber si el input está funcionando y está todo perfecto, ese no es el problema. Mi duda es cuando subo el json como accedo al contenido de ese json para despues trabajar con él.

```js
 function handleFileSelect(e) {
                
                console.log("se subio el json")
            }

            document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Dónde deseas leer esa información? En el cliente (navegador)? O en el servidor?

Comment: Deseo leerlo en el servidor

Comment: Entonces muestra el código del servidor, en donde recibes ese archivo. Tu servidor está escrito en PHP, Node, Python, C#, Java? Aclara eso también. Considera leer [mcve]. Saludos